# How to send a message to Microsoft Teams from POSTMAN

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to Post a Message from Post Man to Microsoft Teams can anyone please help me out with the steps. I download Microsoft Team in my personal Laptop and created Channel to which i want to send a message. Is it mandatory to create a BOT or we can use existing bots provided by Microsoft ?

Comment: Please follow these steps to [send message to Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/send-via-connectors) from postman.

Comment: Did you ever find an example or tutorial?